# Proving the Modal Logic S5-Theorem ♦□ϕ ↔ □ϕ

Tags: modal-logic

[image: ♦□ϕ ↔ □ϕ]

As above (http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ss15/ml/script.pdf page 59), and in many other sources, the formula  ♦□ϕ ↔ □ϕ is considered a theorem in modal logic S5.

However, the paper does not describe how the theorem is proven. Nor could I find a proof online. How can this theorem be proven from the axioms of modal logic?

Comment: □ϕ → □□ϕ → ♦□ϕ by S4 and weakening, ♦□ϕ → □ϕ is the contrapositive of S5.

Comment: Why are we allowed to start with □ϕ?

Comment: Because to prove A ↔ B one has to start with A and prove B, and vice versa. It makes no difference which direction goes first.